# How to set password show/hide eye button in Django form

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

First, I will try to solve this problem using native HTML and jquery, but I want to solve this problem in Django form without any script.

I will try [this](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/bootstrap-show-hidetoggle-password-input-field-using-bootstrap-show-passwordjs-pluginexample.html) source code.

My expected output is put this same example in the above link to Django form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class CustomerLoginFrom(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserLogin
        fields = ['user_name','password']
        labels = {
            "user_name": "*Username",
            "password": "*Password"
        }    
        widgets = {
            "user_name":  TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'ex:test','autocomplete': 'off'}), 
            "password": PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'********','autocomplete': 'off','data-toggle': 'password'}),
        }
```

> `<input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" data-toggle="password">`

Django password field to add HTML attributes directly to Django form attrs, it works for me.

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: Not working for me either. The solution seems incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I see this question has more than 4 years, but as I see a response from months ago in @muthu response, I add mine here.

I've searched for HTML support for this show/hide icon. Nothing yet.
I haven't found any Django module supporting this, so I have created mine today. It adds a new Field to Django that shows this eye icon.

https://pypi.org/project/django-password-eye/1.0.3/