# Django admin field form add css and show/hide password

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have extended a Change password template, but I want to add on all the fields a button for showing/hiding password. How can I do this, below is the template and as well as increasing the height of the input text boxes :

```
{% extends '../base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Password change</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
      <p>
        {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
        {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
          <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
        {% endif %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
      </p>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">CHANGE MY PASSWORD</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

This was a Django admin template `registration/password_change_form.html` but I have overriden it.

Below is what I get :
[image]

Comment: Does it help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56562496/how-to-set-password-show-hide-eye-button-in-django-form

Comment: Hi @Amin, that seems to be with mode.Form, I saw it , but it didn't work, maybe I skipped something

Comment: You just need to add some JavaScript and a button with the function being called to your template https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_password.asp